# postgresql sequence nextval in schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a sequence on postgresql 9.3 inside a schema.

I can do this:

```
SELECT last_value, increment_by from foo."SQ_ID";`
```

```
last_value | increment_by
------------+--------------
          1 |            1 (1 fila)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
SELECT nextval('foo.SQ_ID');
```

```
ERROR:  no existe la relación «foo.sq_id»
LÍNEA 1: SELECT nextval('foo.SQ_ID');
```

What is wrong ?

It says that  not exist the relation `foo.sq_id`, but it exists.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The quoting rules are painful. I think you want:

```
SELECT nextval('foo."SQ_ID"');
```

to prevent case-folding of `SQ_ID`.

Comment: SQL does not "case fold"  in SQL the double quote is for denoting db objects seq and table names the single quote is for denoting static string values .  They are not interchangeable.  select "field" from "table" where "field" = 'value';

Comment: Of all the combinations of single and double quotes I tried, this would have been my last guess.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT last_value, increment_by from "other_schema".id_seq;
```

for adding a seq to a column where the schema is not public try this.

```
nextval('"other_schema".id_seq'::regclass)
```