# Get nextvalue of sequence in postgres using JPA and not native query

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, sequence

I have a sequence created using flyway in postgres which should start from 10000.

I want to get the next value of the sequence using JPA and not a native query , since i have different db platforms being run at different cloud providers.

I'm not able to find a JPA query to get the next value of a sequence, please redirect me to the right page if i am missing something already ..

Thanks for any help in that area though already!

P.S : I found this link which helps me doing the same with native query.
[postgresql sequence nextval in schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397601/postgresql-sequence-nextval-in-schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in a direct way.

JPA doesn't know about sequences.
Only the implementation knows about those and utilizes them to create ids.

I see the following options to get it to work anyway:

1. create a view in the database with a single row and a single column containing the next value. You can query that with native SQL which should be the same for all databases since it is a trivial select.
2. Create a dummy entity using the sequence for id generation, save a new instance and let JPA populate the id.
   A horrible workaround but pure JPA.
3. Bite the bullet and create a simple class that provides the correct native SQL statement to use for the current environment and execute it via `JdbcTemplate`.